# Regex to escape question mark from URL using java/ tuckey URL rewriter

Tags: java, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to use tuckey URL rewriter and java to redirect all URLs with a certain request parameter. So for example I'd like to convert all of the following:

http://xxx.com/?refcode=1234

to simply http://xxx.com/

First of all is tuckey url rewriting the best way to go about this? Using tuckey, I've managed to match URL such as ...co/refcode=1234 (without the ?) using something like this:

```
<rule>
    <note>Remove agent ID from URL without query parameters</note>
    <from>^/.*refcode=.*$</from>
    <to type="redirect">/redirect.do</to>
</rule>
```

but I can't seem to write a regex that would match the ? as well. I've tried escaping the ? (using \?) and I've also tried to use regexs with [?] with no luck. So something along these lines doesn't seem to work:

```
 <rule>
    <note>Remove agent ID from URL without query parameters</note>
    <from>^/[?]agentId=.*$</from>
    <to type="redirect">/bank.do</to>
</rule>
```

OR

```
<rule>
    <note>Remove agent ID from URL without query parameters</note>
    <from>^/\?agentId=.*$</from>
    <to type="redirect">/bank.do</to>
</rule>
```

Would really appreciate if someone can let me know how I can go about writing the correct regex to match this URL

Answer (score 0):

\? is the correct way to escape the ?, I would avoid using the $ at the end.

```
<from>^/\?refcode=(\d+)</from>
```

You could also use the CONDITION tag

```
<condition type="query-string">refcode=(\d+)</condition>
<from>/</from>
```

Comment: using the condition tag with type="parameter" seemed to work for me. thanks for the lead.